# Creating an instance of Trial2Vec() and getting back a response as Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to use the pytrial library from: [https://github.com/RyanWangZf/PyTrial](https://stackoverflow.com) to reproduce the results from its example:
[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11-vhoHeV5hzsE-pfdh9mRL3PbwsLA-Cv?usp=sharing#scrollTo=H-8WEZ6Lbk1o](https://stackoverflow.com)

The problem comes when I try to create the model using

```
model = Trial2Vec()
```

I get this error:

> raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
> AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Since I have a macOS, I tried to use metal to install PyTorch with and then I tried to set the device to cpu and mps:

```
    device = torch.device("mps")
    model = Trial2Vec(device=device)
```

I get the same error as before

and:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = Trial2Vec(device=device)
```

But keep getting the same error.

Has anybody faced this same error?